# Error message in MemberShip method

Tags: asp.net

Hello I have been having trouble with this for a while now. I added twelve textbox 
in the code behind(XXX.aspx.cs). i get message error for this line:

```
      Membership.CreateUser(HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(sFirstName.Trim()),
                 HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(sLastName.Trim()),
```

Why i'm getting this is the message: overload for method 'CreateUser' takes 12 arguments.
I like to mention that before i had 5 textbox and it's worked well. Now, after i added 5 textbox, i'm getting the message above.

Answer (score 0):

[`Membership.GetUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser.aspx) has several overloads. It seems as if you want to use the one with two parameters for username and password.

But your code snippet above shows a comma at the end which suggests that you have more parameters or at least that it's not compiling code.

This should work:

```
Membership.CreateUser(
  HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(sFirstName.Trim()),
  HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(sLastName.Trim()));
```

Comment: Thanks, I had five parameters and it use to be work well. When i added six paramter, i get this message:overload for method 'CreateUser' takes 12 arguments(and i use in Membership.CreateUser).If i want to use in 11 parametrs, can i use in Membership.CreateUser?

Comment: `CreateUser` has several overloads as i've mentioned and linked. There is none with 12 parameters. Have a look at the methods available and choose the one you need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser.aspx